# jQuery validate and deferred objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-deferred

I have a form that is using the jQuery validate functionality, with some custom functions validating the values with ajax posts.

My problem is when I submit the form, I have the submitHandler do ajax post to check if the field is valid by checking in the DB. I only want the form to submit if the value returned is valid.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.checkValidSubDomain = function (params) {
        params['siteID'] = wlSiteID;
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var promise = deferred.promise();

        $("div#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Info").html(copyItems["info_checkingStatus"]);
        var jqxhr = $(this).ajaxPost('checkValidSubDomain', params)
        jqxhr.success(function (data){
            if (data.validSubdomain) {
                $("div#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Info").html(copyItems["info_"+$(this).attr('id')+"Available"]);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            } else {
                $("div#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Info").html(copyItems["err_"+$(this).attr('id')+"Unavailable"]);
                deferred.reject(jqxhr, 'error');
            }
        })
        jqxhr.error(function (jqXHR, status, error){
            $("div#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Info").html(copyItems["err_"+$(this).attr('id')+"Unavailable"]);
            deferred.reject(jqXHR, status, error);
        });
        return promise;
    };
})(jQuery);

var validationRules = {
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var promise;
        if ($('input[name="domainSetting"]:checked').val() == 'subDomain') {
            alert("checking subdomain - " + $('#subDomainSiteName').val())
            promise = $('#subDomainSiteName').checkValidSubDomain({'subDomain': $('#subDomainSiteName').val(), 'domain':$("#domainSelect option:selected").val()});
        } 
        promise.done(function() {
            form.submit();
        });
        return false;
    },
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        subDomainSiteName: {
            required: {
                depends: '#domainSettingSubDomain:checked'
            }
        }
    }
};
$('#domainSettingsFRM').formValidation(validationRules);
```

I'm not sure how I get to the form to only submit if the field is valid. Currently, it's just showing the alert and then submitting the form regardless of the value.

Any help appreciated

**EDIT**

I think I just figured it out. Once the async ajax call is finished, the promise.done() will trigger. At that point I simply check the state to see if it is resolved or rejected. Changing the code to the following seems to do the trick.

```
promise.done(function() {
    if (promise.state() == "resolved") {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')`? You can simply use `this.id`

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I get carried away

Comment: If, as it would appear, you only ever invoke `checkValidSubDomain()` on `$('#subDomainSiteName')`, then there's little point writing `checkValidSubDomain()` as a jQuery plugin. The only reason not to do everything inside the submitHander would be a scope issue to do with `wlSiteID` but that could be overcome by more simple means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without seeing a demo page with that code, at a first look that behaviour could be due to a javascript error: where you wrote

```
 promise.done()(function() {
            form.submit();
 }, null);
```

you should write instead

```
 promise.done(function() {
     form.submit();
 });
```

Comment: so please check if you have javascript error on the console and post a working demo page

Comment: the line `promise.done()` is throwing a _Uncought TypeError: object is not a function_. I'm not sure why, I've added some debugging alerts in showing `promise.state()` and those are working.

Comment: Bleh, just figured that error out now, it's should be `promise.done(function() ....` and not `promise.done()(function()....` don't know what I was doing there.

Comment: your workaround seems really strange to me: your deferred is resolved when ajax executes success method. But maybe I'm missing smthg of your code...

Comment: I set the object to rejected the in the subdomain isn't valid `jqxhr.success(function (data){
            if (data.validSubdomain) {
                $("div#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Info").html(copyItems["info_"+$(this).attr('id')+"Available"]);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            } else {
                $("div#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Info").html(copyItems["err_"+$(this).attr('id')+"Unavailable"]);
                deferred.reject(jqxhr, 'error');
            }
        })`